# Найти range одного цвета на изображении

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

Не получается найти range одного цвета на изображении. Пример изображения:

[image: Пример]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# RGB: 77, 82, 89
hsv_min = np.array([215, 13, 34], np.uint8)  # <- HSV
# RGB: 32, 40, 49
hsv_max = np.array([212, 35, 20], np.uint8)  # <- HSV

hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

result = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, hsv_min, hsv_max)
cv2.imwrite('output.png', result)
```

output:

[image: Результат]

Нужно найти цвет, который находится в круге слева вверху. Брал пипеткой у края самый яркий цвет и из центра самый темный, пытался найти его - не выходит. Изменял значения min range на 0.8 и max на 1.2 от исходных значений - то же самое. Много всего перепробовал.

Как все-таки это работает? Как можно найти только нужный цвет на изображении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По координатам центра круга мы можем найти искомый цвет в HSV:

```
In [116]: hsv_pt = hsv_img[25,25]

In [117]: hsv_pt
Out[117]: array([106,  88,  49], dtype=uint8)
```

теперь попробуем ваш код с "правильным" диапазоном цветов:

```
hsv_min = (hsv_pt * 0.95).astype('uint8')
hsv_max = (hsv_pt * 1.05).astype('uint8')

result = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, hsv_min, hsv_max)

cv2.imwrite('d:/temp/output.png', result)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]