# Вопрос по работе с numpy array

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, numpy

Имеется функция auto_canny, которая используется для перевода изображение в edged:

```
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    v = np.median(image)
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    return cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
```

В итоге получается черное изображение с найденными белыми контурами. При принте результата numpy array показывает только числа 0 (черный) и 255 (белый).

Как можно пройтись по X оси (горизонтальной)? Дело такое: к примеру, нужно иметь возможность пройтись только по первой линии по оси X, не спускаясь вниз по оси Y (например, при разрешении 800x600 нужно пройтись по самой верхней линии с восьмиста пикселями). Я делал примерно так:

```
y_array, x_array = np.where(result != 0)
```

Тогда у меня был x_array с точками X вместо цветов, я ничего не придумал умнее, чем сравнивать число с предыдущим. То есть, если есть последовательность `456 511 599 612 10`, то `10` уже является след. строкой, верно?

Вариант отпал, потому что еще требуется найти среди строк первое совпадение, где на строке вообще не будет белого цвета, т.е. не будет контуров. Но так как я убрал все "пустые" значения, то найти пустую строку с одними нулями здесь не выйдет, она была пропущена.

Конечным результатом должен быть номер первой строки, которая попадется пустой при перебирании их сверху вниз, плюс должна быть возможность произвести вычисления с самой верхней строкой, а именно с её X-координатами.

Код за меня писать не прошу, достаточно просто направить в нужную сторону. Спасибо.

Comment: вы можете привести пример входной Numpy матрицы и пример(ы) того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с [картинкой из вашего первого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664361/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-range-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8):

```
fn = r'D:\download\image.png'
img = cv2.imread(fn)
r = auto_canny(img)
```

Первая строка:

```
In [21]: r[0]
Out[21]:
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)

In [22]: len(r[0])
Out[22]: 600
```

X координаты "не черных" точек для 51-й (индекс == 50) строки:

```
In [20]: np.where(r[50] > 0)
Out[20]: (array([ 53,  54, 172, 173, 208, 209, 316, 317, 382, 383, 400, 401, 441, 442, 458, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 542, 543], dtype=int64)
,)
```

показать цвет "не черных" точек в строке с индексом 25:

```
In [23]: r[25, r[25] > 0]
Out[23]: array([255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

их индексы по оси X (столбцы):

```
In [24]: np.where(r[25] > 0)
Out[24]: (array([10, 39], dtype=int64),)

In [25]: np.nonzero(r[25])
Out[25]: (array([10, 39], dtype=int64),)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]